# Shell script Error : Conditional biinary operator expected

Tags: shell

I am getting the error "Conditional binary operator expected in the following script.

```
if [[ $LOCALE -eq 'US' ]]; then
RWLOGGROUPNAME=/US/Live/access-log
DPXLOGGROUPNAME=/US/Live/access-log
END_POINT=https://us.ginger.com
fi

if [[ $LOCALE -eq 'DE' || $LOCALE -eq 'FR' || $LOCALE -eq 'IT' ||  $LOCALE -eq 'UK' ]]; then
RWLOGGROUPNAME=$LOCALE/Live/access-log
DPXLOGGROUPNAME=$LOCALE/Prod/access_log
END_POINT=https://eu.ginger.com
fi
```

Can some one tell me what is going wrong here. I am taking locale from command line and have put it in quotes as it's a string.The first if works fine but the next one does not.

Answer (score 1):

`-eq` is used for integer comparison only, moreover you are using `eq` at few places instead of `-eq`.

Make it:

```
if [ "$LOCALE" = "DE" -o "$LOCALE" = "FR" -o "$LOCALE" = "IT" -o "$LOCALE" = "UK" ]; then
```

Comment: I have it in code . It somehow got removed while posting the issue here :)

Comment: ok check updated answer now. You cannot use `-eq` for string comparison.